# Terraform passing list/set from root module to child module issue

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have this root module which calls the child module to create a GCP project and create IAM role bindings.

```
module "test_project" {
  source         = "terraform.dev.mydomain.com/Dev/sbxprjmodule/google"
  version        = "1.0.3"
  short_name     = "looker-nwtest"
  owner_bindings = ["group:npe-cloud-platformeng-contractors@c.mydomain.com", "group:npe-sbox-rw-tfetraining@c.mydomain.com"]
}

variable "owner_bindings" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = null
}
```

This is the child module which does the assignments

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "g-sbox-iam-owner" {
  count = var.owner_bindings == null ? 0 : length(var.owner_bindings)
  project = "${var.project_id}-${var.short_name}"
  role    = "roles/owner"
  members = [var.owner_bindings[count.index]]
}

variable "owner_bindings" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = null
}
/*
```

When I do a terraform plan and apply, it creates both the bindings properly, looping through twice. Then when I run a terraform plan again and apply,  it shows this change below.

```
# module.lookernwtest_project.google_project_iam_binding.g-sbox-iam-owner[0] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_project_iam_binding" "g-sbox-iam-owner" {
        id      = "g-prj-npe-sbox-looker-nwtest/roles/owner"
      ~ members = [
          + "group:npe-cloud-platformeng-contractors@c.mydomain.com",
          - "group:npe-sbox-rw-tfetraining@c.mydomain.com",
        ]
        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Next time I do a terraform plan and apply, it shows the below. It then alternates between the two of the groups on each subsequent plan and apply.

```
# module.lookernwtest_project.google_project_iam_binding.g-sbox-iam-owner[1] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_project_iam_binding" "g-sbox-iam-owner" {
        id      = "g-prj-npe-sbox-looker-nwtest/roles/owner"
      ~ members = [
          - "group:npe-cloud-platformeng-contractors@c.relayhealth.com",
          + "group:npe-sbox-rw-tfetraining@c.relayhealth.com",
        ]
        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Tried to change the data structure from list to set and had the same issue.
The groups are not inherited and are applied only at the project level too. So not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: Expected behavior is, for the same code without any changes and when we run subsequent terraform plan/apply, shouldn't it show the message that there are no further changes as the code matches the configuration? Why does it change the underlying infrastructure each time it is run?

Comment: If those groups all have the same role `"roles/owner"` do we need to create individual iam_binding ? ... Maybe there should not be any count there and you pass the entire owner_bindings to the members

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Have updated above based on your comments. Doesnt it create an individual iam_binding each time it loops? That was my understanding., I'm beginning to think this might be a state issue with Terraform or something I misunderstood with states.

Comment: ... And in your latest code the plan does not match the code, with `for_each` you should no longer see those numeric array  `g-sbox-iam-owner[0]` ... feels like you are still getting the old version of that child module

Comment: but the question is: Why do we need individual iam_binding if they all will have the same role?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda yes, you were right with the above two comments. I had missed to update the module version. And also, instead of using a loop, if I pass the value directly instead of a loop. It worked fine. I was thinking it needed individual bindings as that is how it is displayed in GCP IAM. Owners/Editors are not grouped, but in Terraform looks like thats the right way to go. Thanks for your help. I'll update the changes and mark answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `count` you can use a `for_each` the change is simple...

the resource in your child module will look something like this:

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "g-sbox-iam-owner" {
  for_each = var.owner_bindings == null ? toset([]) : toset(var.owner_bindings)  
  project  = "${var.project_id}-${var.short_name}"
  role     = "roles/owner"
  members  = [each.value]
}
```

The count changes for_each and in the members we use the each.value

---

With a `for_each` the state changes, you will no longer see the numeric array:

```txt
# module.lookernwtest_project.google_project_iam_binding.g-sbox-iam-owner[0]
...
# module.lookernwtest_project.google_project_iam_binding.g-sbox-iam-owner[1]
```

instead it will have the names, something like:

```txt
# module.lookernwtest_project.google_project_iam_binding.g-sbox-iam-owner["abc"]
...
# module.lookernwtest_project.google_project_iam_binding.g-sbox-iam-owner["def"]
```

---

### To loop or not to loop

After looking at this for a while; I'm questioning why do we need individual iam_binding if they all will have the same role, if all members have the same "roles/owner" we could just do:

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "g-sbox-iam-owner" {
  project = "${var.project_id}-${var.short_name}"
  role    = "roles/owner"
  members = [var.owner_bindings]
}
```

Comment: As I said in the post, I tried using set instead of list and we need to use for_each for sets, but still the same issue.

Comment: @Vikram but are you using a `for_each` ? ... that is the key there, that should not happen with a for

Comment: Yes, the above code worked. Thank you.